JPA - Make 2 columns refer to the same column in different table
Spring boot JPA newbie here. I have an Account entity as below
@Entity
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long accNo;

private Double balance = 0.0;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
private UserInfo userInfo;

I have a Transaction entity as below:
@Entity
public class Transaction {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private UUID transactionID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fromAccount")
private Account fromAccount;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "toAccount")
private Account toAccount;

private Double amount;

private Double balance;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

I want to make sure that fromAccount and toAccount are always a valid accNo in Account.
I tried using below which gives compilation errors.
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fromAccount")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "toAccount")
private Long accNo;

I can see it can be done in PostgreSql but how to do it in JPA ? Any advice is much appreciated.

You need to use two oneToMany relationships with Transaction entity for bidirectional relation.
@OneToMany(mappedBy="fromAccount")
private Collection<Transaction> fromAcc;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="toAccount")
private Collection<Transaction> toAcc;

